# JAXB complex mapping

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I have the following code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "repository")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Repository
{
    @XmlElement (name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlElement (name = "policy")
    private String policy;
    ...
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "storage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Storage 
{

    @XmlElement (name = "id")
    private String id;

    /**
     * K: repository.id
     * V: Repository
     */
    @XmlElement (name = "repositories")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(RepositoryMapAdapter.class)
    private Map<String, Repository> repositories = new LinkedHashMap<String, Repository>();
    ...
}

public class DataCenter
{
    /**
     * K: storageId
     * V: storage
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "storages")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StorageMapAdapter.class)
    //@XStreamAlias(value = "storages")
    private Map<String, Storage> storages = new LinkedHashMap<String, Storage>();

    ...
}
```

I have the following two adapters:

```
public class RepositoryMapAdapter
        extends XmlAdapter<RepositoryMapAdapter.RepositoryMap, Map<String, Repository>>
{

    public static class RepositoryMap
    {
        @XmlVariableNode("id")
        List<RepositoryMapEntry> entries = new ArrayList<RepositoryMapEntry>();
    }

    public static class RepositoryMapEntry
    {
        @XmlAttribute
        public String id;

        @XmlValue
        public Repository repository;
    }

    @Override
    public RepositoryMap marshal(Map<String, Repository> map)
            throws Exception
    {
        RepositoryMap repositoryMap = new RepositoryMap();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Repository> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            RepositoryMapEntry repositoryMapEntry = new RepositoryMapEntry();
            repositoryMapEntry.id = entry.getKey();
            repositoryMapEntry.repository = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println("Writing repository " + entry.getValue().getId());

            repositoryMap.entries.add(repositoryMapEntry);
        }

        return repositoryMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Repository> unmarshal(RepositoryMap repositoryMap)
            throws Exception
    {
        List<RepositoryMapEntry> adaptedEntries = repositoryMap.entries;

        Map<String, Repository> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Repository>(adaptedEntries.size());
        for (RepositoryMapEntry repositoryMapEntry : adaptedEntries)
        {
            System.out.println("Reading repository " + repositoryMapEntry.id);
            map.put(repositoryMapEntry.id, repositoryMapEntry.repository);
        }

        return map;
    }

}

public class StorageMapAdapter
        extends XmlAdapter<StorageMapAdapter.StorageMap, Map<String, Storage>>
{

    public static class StorageMap
    {
        @XmlVariableNode("id")
        List<StorageMapEntry> entries = new ArrayList<StorageMapEntry>();
    }

    public static class StorageMapEntry
    {
        @XmlAttribute
        public String id;

        @XmlValue
        public Storage storage;
    }

    @Override
    public StorageMap marshal(Map<String, Storage> map)
            throws Exception
    {
        StorageMap storageMap = new StorageMap();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Storage> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            StorageMapEntry storageMapEntry = new StorageMapEntry();
            storageMapEntry.id = entry.getKey();
            storageMapEntry.storage = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println("Writing storage " + entry.getValue().getId());

            storageMap.entries.add(storageMapEntry);
        }

        return storageMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Storage> unmarshal(StorageMap storageMap)
            throws Exception
    {
        List<StorageMapEntry> adaptedEntries = storageMap.entries;

        Map<String, Storage> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Storage>(adaptedEntries.size());
        for (StorageMapEntry storageMapEntry : adaptedEntries)
        {
            System.out.println("Reading storage " + storageMapEntry.id);
            map.put(storageMapEntry.id, storageMapEntry.storage);
        }

        return map;
    }

}
```

I'd like to have the following `XML`:

```
<storages>
    <storage id="storage0">
        <repositories>
            <repository id="repository1" policy="policy1"/>
            <repository id="repository2" policy="policy2"/>
        </repositories>
    </storage>
    <storage id="storage1">
        <repositories>
            <repository id="repository3" />
            <repository id="repository4" />
        </repositories>
    </storage>
</storages>
```

Based on the above XML, what more do I need to do in order to have my code read/write such `XML` using JAXB? As far as I understand, I need to use `XmlAdapter`, but I'm not quite sure how to apply it to this case.

Comment: `Map<String, Repository>`: what would the `key` be?

Comment: Yes, it would be the `repository.id`.

Comment: If you just want to read/write that xml, using a List instead of Map would be much easier to bind: is that feasible?

Comment: It must be a map. A lot of code is already based on the same Java excerpt I showed. You need maps for both the storages and repositorys with `K: id`, `V: theObject`.

Comment: What version of JAXB are we talking about here? The JAXB version matters because there are some differences in certain activities if you use an older version of JAXB rather than the one that comes with Java 7. The reason I know this is because I went through this while doing a Java 7 migration.

Comment: JAXB is very specific about how it converts an XML document into an object.  In my opinion, the best thing to do is to run the XJC compiler and generate the JAXB classes you will need.  Then, you can create some sort of adapter to map these generated JAXB classes to the classes you showed in your original post. As guido stated, JAXB uses list to represent objects that contain a collection of more than one elements of the same type.  This is why you would need to either use those generated classes directly or create adapters for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something in the lines of:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "datacenter")
public class DataCenter {
    /**
     * K: storageId V: storage
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "storages")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StorageMapAdapter.class)
    private final Map<String, Storage> storages = new LinkedHashMap<String, Storage>();
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StorageMapAdapter.class)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Storage {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    /**
     * K: repository.id V: Repository
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "repositories")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(RepositoryMapAdapter.class)
    private final Map<String, Repository> repositories = new LinkedHashMap<String, Repository>();

}

public class StorageMap {
    @XmlElement(name = "storage")
    List<Storage> entries = new ArrayList<Storage>();

    public List<Storage> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }
}

public class StorageMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<StorageMap, Map<String, Storage>> {

    @Override
    public StorageMap marshal(Map<String, Storage> map) throws Exception {
        StorageMap storageMap = new StorageMap();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Storage> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            storageMap.getEntries().add(entry.getValue());
        }
        return storageMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Storage> unmarshal(StorageMap storageMap) throws Exception {
        List<Storage> adaptedEntries = storageMap.entries;
        Map<String, Storage> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Storage>(adaptedEntries.size());
        for (Storage storage : adaptedEntries) {
            map.put(storage.getId(), storage);
        }
        return map;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "repository")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Repository {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "policy")
    private String policy;
}

public class RepositoryMap {
    @XmlElement(name = "repository")
    List<Repository> entries = new ArrayList<Repository>();

    public List<Repository> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }
}

public class RepositoryMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<RepositoryMap, Map<String, Repository>> {

    @Override
    public RepositoryMap marshal(Map<String, Repository> map) throws Exception {
        RepositoryMap repositoryMap = new RepositoryMap();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Repository> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            repositoryMap.getEntries().add(entry.getValue());
        }
        return repositoryMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Repository> unmarshal(RepositoryMap repositoryMap) throws Exception {
        List<Repository> adaptedEntries = repositoryMap.entries;
        Map<String, Repository> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Repository>(adaptedEntries.size());
        for (Repository repository : adaptedEntries) {
            System.out.println("Reading repository " + repository.getId());
            map.put(repository.getId(), repository);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Running demo here: http://ideone.com/NyOGVQ
Demo updated with marshalling here: http://ideone.com/NzvRzX

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have slightly updated/changed the question. Would it be possible for you to help me get this working?

Comment: @carlspring what is not working with the updated code at the moment? (I'd suggest to move RepositoryMap and RepositoryEntry out of the adapter, and non-static, because I remember I had issues with jaxb unmarshalling elements in inner classes).

Comment: When storing/parsing the XML, the `<storage/>` is empty.

Comment: try removing XmlElement() annotation from the storage class field, and annotate RepositoriesMap as XmlRootElement() (in a non-inner, non-static class)

Comment: I'd basically like the `@XmlValue public String value` to be the actual object such as `Storage storage`. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: ok now i get it, sorry i did over-engineer it because i was thinking repositories had a text node inside... pls see updated answer

Comment: Thanks a million! This helped so much! It solves all my issues! :)

Comment: @carlspring I edited the demo with the marshalling back to xml, not sure is what you want.... edit: ah ok, didn't see you latest message, you welcome mate

Comment: It does exactly what I need! This is for an OSS project of mine. Got and e-mail and care to keep in touch?

Comment: why not, if it is on github or bitbucket i might join

Comment: My e-mail is my username `@gmail.com`. Drop me a line and I'll share some details. :)